# Texmaker file does not quick build, only hangs

Tags: texmaker

I've been using Texmaker for quite some time now with no issues. I'm currently trying to get an old file which uses an old (custom) package to compile. Call them oldfile.tex and oldpackage.sty, respectively. Originally, the message log would throw me an error because of "psamsfonts" being obsolete, so within oldpackage.sty I made the following change:

```
%\usepackage[psamsfonts]{amssymb}   %OLD LINE
 \usepackage{amssymb}               %NEW LINE
```

Now, when I click "Quick Build", the message log doesn't alert me to any errors. However, it also doesn't finish building; it just hangs there. Within the folder containing oldfile.tex are two new files, oldfile.log and oldfile.synctex.gz(busy). Here is the oldfile.log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.7.24)  22 APR 2015 15:44
entering extended mode
**oldfile.tex
("C:\Users\User\Desktop\oldpackage LaTeX files\TeX\oldfile.tex"
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\book.cls"
Document Class: book 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\bk10.clo"
File: bk10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(C:\LocalTeXMF\tex\latex\oldpackage\oldpackage.sty
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pstricks\pstricks.sty"
Package: pstricks 2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\base\pstricks.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\pst-xkey.tex"
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/05/25 v2.7 package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count88
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/05/25 v2.7 key=value parser (HA)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\base\pst-fp.tex"
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count89
\pstFP@xia=\count90
\pstFP@xib=\count91
\pstFP@xfa=\count92
\pstFP@xfb=\count93
\pstFP@rega=\count94
\pstFP@regb=\count95
\pstFP@regs=\count96
\pstFP@times=\count97
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex"
\pgf@x=\dimen105
\pgf@xa=\dimen106
\pgf@xb=\dimen107
\pgf@xc=\dimen108
\pgf@y=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@yb=\dimen111
\pgf@yc=\dimen112
\c@pgf@counta=\count98
\c@pgf@countb=\count99
\c@pgf@countc=\count100
\c@pgf@countd=\count101
\pgfutil@tempcnta=\count102
\pgfutil@tempcntb=\count103
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen113
\pgfmath@count=\count104
\pgfmath@box=\box26
\pgfmath@toks=\toks20
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks21
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks22
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count105
))
\pgffor@iter=\dimen114
\pgffor@skip=\dimen115
\pgffor@stack=\toks23
\pgffor@toks=\toks24
)
\psLoopIndex=\count106

`PSTricks' v2.54a   (tvz)
\pst@dima=\dimen116
\pst@dimb=\dimen117
\pst@dimc=\dimen118
\pst@dimd=\dimen119
\pst@dimg=\dimen120
\pst@dimh=\dimen121
\pst@dimm=\dimen122
\pst@dimn=\dimen123
\pst@dimo=\dimen124
\pst@dimp=\dimen125
\pst@hbox=\box27
\pst@ibox=\box28
\pst@boxg=\box29
\pst@cnta=\count107
\pst@cntb=\count108
\pst@cntc=\count109
\pst@cntd=\count110
\pst@cntg=\count111
\pst@cnth=\count112
\pst@cntm=\count113
\pst@cntn=\count114
\pst@cnto=\count115
\pst@cntp=\count116
\@zero=\count117
\pst@toks=\toks25
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\base\pstricks.con")
\psunit=\dimen126
\psxunit=\dimen127
\psyunit=\dimen128
\pst@C@@rType=\count118
\pslinewidth=\dimen129
\psk@startLW=\dimen130
\psk@endLW=\dimen131
\pst@customdefs=\toks26
\pslinearc=\dimen132
\pst@symbolStep=\dimen133
\pst@symbolWidth=\dimen134
\pst@symbolLinewidth=\dimen135
\everypsbox=\toks27
\psframesep=\dimen136
\pslabelsep=\dimen137
\sh@wgridXunit=\dimen138
\sh@wgridYunit=\dimen139
\pst@shift=\dimen140
)
File: pstricks.tex 2014/05/19 v2.54a `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\base\pst-fp.tex")
File: pst-fp.tex 2014/05/19 v2.54a `PST-fp' (hv)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count119
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\colortbl\colortbl.sty"
Package: colortbl 2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\array.sty"
Package: array 2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen141
\extrarowheight=\dimen142
\NC@list=\toks28
\extratabsurround=\skip43
\backup@length=\skip44
)
\everycr=\toks29
\minrowclearance=\skip45
)
(C:\LocalTeXMF\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\LocalTeXMF\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\LocalTeXMF\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: textures.def on input line 91.

(C:\LocalTeXMF\tex\latex\graphics\textures.def
File: textures.def 1997/5/28 v0.3 Graphics extensions for Textures 1.7 and late
r (Arthur Ogawa/ogawa@teleport.com)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen143
\Gin@req@width=\dimen144
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip46

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks30
\ex@=\dimen145
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen146
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count120
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count121
\leftroot@=\count122
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count123
\DOTSCASE@=\count124
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box30
\strutbox@=\box31
\big@size=\dimen147
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count125
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count126
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count127
\dspbrk@lvl=\count128
\tag@help=\toks31
\row@=\count129
\column@=\count130
\maxfields@=\count131
\andhelp@=\toks32
\eqnshift@=\dimen148
\alignsep@=\dimen149
\tagshift@=\dimen150
\tagwidth@=\dimen151
\totwidth@=\dimen152
\lineht@=\dimen153
\@envbody=\toks33
\multlinegap=\skip47
\multlinetaggap=\skip48
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks34
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
)
(C:\LocalTeXMF\tex\latex\mycolor\mycolor.sty
Package: mycolor 1999/02/16 v1.0i Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \color on input line 71.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 125.
Package color Info: Redefining color black on input line 159.
Package color Info: Redefining color white on input line 160.
Package color Info: Redefining color red on input line 163.
Package color Info: Redefining color green on input line 164.
Package color Info: Redefining color blue on input line 165.
Package color Info: Redefining color cyan on input line 169.
Package color Info: Redefining color magenta on input line 170.
Package color Info: Redefining color yellow on input line 171.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\multicol.sty"
Package: multicol 2014/06/19 v1.8f multicolumn formatting (FMi)
\c@tracingmulticols=\count132
\mult@box=\box32
\multicol@leftmargin=\dimen154
\c@unbalance=\count133
\c@collectmore=\count134
\doublecol@number=\count135
\multicoltolerance=\count136
\multicolpretolerance=\count137
\full@width=\dimen155
\page@free=\dimen156
\premulticols=\dimen157
\postmulticols=\dimen158
\multicolsep=\skip49
\multicolbaselineskip=\skip50
\partial@page=\box33
\last@line=\box34
\maxbalancingoverflow=\dimen159
\mult@rightbox=\box35
\mult@grightbox=\box36
\mult@gfirstbox=\box37
\mult@firstbox=\box38
\@tempa=\box39
\@tempa=\box40
\@tempa=\box41
\@tempa=\box42
\@tempa=\box43
\@tempa=\box44
\@tempa=\box45
\@tempa=\box46
\@tempa=\box47
\@tempa=\box48
\@tempa=\box49
\@tempa=\box50
\@tempa=\box51
\@tempa=\box52
\@tempa=\box53
\@tempa=\box54
\@tempa=\box55
\c@columnbadness=\count138
\c@finalcolumnbadness=\count139
\last@try=\dimen160
\multicolovershoot=\dimen161
\multicolundershoot=\dimen162
\mult@nat@firstbox=\box56
\colbreak@box=\box57
\mc@col@check@num=\count140
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty"
Package: calc 2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count141
\calc@Bcount=\count142
\calc@Adimen=\dimen163
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen164
\calc@Askip=\skip51
\calc@Bskip=\skip52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 75.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 76.
\calc@Ccount=\count143
\calc@Cskip=\skip53
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fixltx2e.sty"
Package: fixltx2e 2014/06/10 v1.1r fixes to LaTeX
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 430.
LaTeX Info: The control sequence `\[' is already robust on input line 481.
LaTeX Info: The control sequence `\]' is already robust on input line 482.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\footmisc\footmisc.sty"
Package: footmisc 2011/06/06 v5.5b a miscellany of footnote facilities
\FN@temptoken=\toks35
\footnotemargin=\dimen165
\FN@tempboxb=\box58
\FN@tempboxc=\box59
\footglue=\skip54
\footnotebaselineskip=\dimen166
\c@pp@next@reset=\count144
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style bringhurst on input line 855.
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style chicago on input line 863.
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style wiley on input line 872.
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style lamport-robust on input line 883.

Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style lamport* on input line 903.
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style lamport*-robust on input line 924
.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\times.sty"
Package: times 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mathtime\mathtime.sty"
Package: mathtime 1999/03/29 v1.1mathtime font support (FMi/DPC)
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/ptm/m/n on input line 77.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OML' has changed to `MY1' for symbol font
(Font)              `letters' in the math version `normal' on input line 78.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> MY1/mtt/m/it on input line 78.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `MY2' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 79.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> MY2/mtt/m/n on input line 79.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `MY3' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 8
0.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> MY3/mtt/m/n on input line 80.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/ptm/b/n on input line 108.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OML' has changed to `MY1' for symbol font
(Font)              `letters' in the math version `bold' on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> MY1/mtt/b/it on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `MY2' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 110.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> MY2/mtt/b/n on input line 110.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `MY3' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 111
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> MY3/mtt/b/n on input line 111.
\c@mv@heavy=\count145
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `heavy'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/ptm/b/n on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OML' has changed to `MY1' for symbol font
(Font)              `letters' in the math version `heavy' on input line 114.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `heavy'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> MY1/mtt/ub/it on input line 114.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `MY2' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `heavy' on input line 115.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `heavy'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> MY2/mtt/ub/n on input line 115.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `MY3' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `heavy' on input line 11
6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `heavy'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> MY3/mtt/ub/n on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/ptm/m/n --> OT1/ptm/m/n on input line 136.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/ptm/b/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/ptm/m/it on input line 138.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/phv/m/n on input line 139.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/pcr/m/n on input line 140.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/ptm/b/n --> OT1/ptm/b/n on input line 143.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/ptm/b/n on input line 144.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/ptm/b/it on input line 145.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/phv/b/n on input line 146.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/pcr/b/n on input line 147.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `heavy'
(Font)                  OT1/ptm/b/n --> OT1/ptm/b/n on input line 151.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `heavy'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/ptm/b/n on input line 152.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `heavy'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/ptm/b/it on input line 153.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `heavy'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/phv/b/n on input line 154.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `heavy'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/pcr/b/n on input line 155.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathscr' in version `normal'
(Font)                  U/mtms/b/n --> U/mtms/m/n on input line 160.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathcal' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 184.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 188.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 189.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 190.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 191.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 192.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 193.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 194.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 195.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 196.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 197.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 198.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varGamma on input line 199.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varDelta on input line 200.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varTheta on input line 201.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varLambda on input line 202.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varXi on input line 203.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varPi on input line 204.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varSigma on input line 205.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varUpsilon on input line 206.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varPhi on input line 207.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varPsi on input line 208.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varOmega on input line 209.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \triangleleft on input line 214.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \triangleright on input line 215.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varkappa on input line 225.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \vec on input line 226.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 227.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 228.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 229.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 230.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 231.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 232.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 233.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 234.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 235.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \hbar on input line 262.
\symtextcomp=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `textcomp' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TS1/ptm/m/n --> TS1/ptm/b/n on input line 297.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `textcomp' in version `heavy'
(Font)                  TS1/ptm/m/n --> TS1/ptm/b/n on input line 301.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \dagger on input line 303.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \ddagger on input line 304.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathsection on input line 305.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathparagraph on input line 306.
)
Package color Info: Redefining color lightgray on input line 38.
Package color Info: Redefining color darkgray on input line 39.
```

As you can see, the message log just stops without giving me and error and without finishing. I've found that commenting out the final lines it gives me make no difference to the ability of the file to compile.
I have reason to believe that the issue is with the package, as even the following bare-bones file just hangs when I try to compile it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[printer]{oldpackage}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Whether I fill in any options for the package or not (e.g. "printer") makes no difference in the file's ability to build. How do I go about resolving this issue and so that the file compiles into a .pdf?

Comment: I notice this message flashing briefly in the message log before it outputs what becomes oldfile.log:
Process started

pdflatex

: Windows API error 1113: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multibyte code page.

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: possibly unrelated to the hang, but the log shows you are using miktex so `(C:\LocalTeXMF\tex\latex\graphics\textures.def` is very wrong, why is it including the mac specific textures back end support?

Comment: You load `pstricks`. If your you does use it, you cannot compile with `pdflatex`, unless you add the `pdf` option to your document class, and add the `--enable-write18` switch to the compiler parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Bernard! Despite you mentioning that, I was able to mysteriously create a .pdf in the directory containing the .tex file after some not-entirely-random removal of certain lines in oldpackage.sty. However, I cannot replicate the process, and the .pdf was not displayed to me as it usually is (so I didn't notice its existence for about 10 minutes). I've also noticed that the message log flashes a "Windows API error 1113" whenever I try to compile.

Comment: The error message normally means that you are trying to include a graphic with non-ASCII chars in its name. And the hanging could mean that miktex is missing a package but can't start the on-the-fly installation. You should compile on the command line to get better error messages - editors with nonstopmode have a tendency to hide a lot.